# How do I use rotary encoders to control an HID device?

Tags: c++, arduino

My goal is to create a small switch panel for my Windows 10 PC. I'm using an Arduino Micro to run my program. I want to use a digital rotary encoder to control Joystick inputs. I want to control volume by pressing volume up when I turn the encoder clockwise, and volume down when I turn it counterclockwise

```
#include <Joystick.h>

#define outputA 2
#define outputB 3


int counter = 0;
int aState;
int aLastState;

void setup() {
  Joystick.begin();
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(3, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  aState = digitalRead(outputA);
  if (aState != aLastState) {
    if (digitalRead(outputB) != aState) {      // Clockwise
      Joystick.pressButton(1);
      delay(10);
      Joystick.releaseButton(1);
      counter ++;
    } else {                   // Counterclockwise
      Joystick.pressButton(2);
      delay(10);
      Joystick.releaseButton(2);
      counter --;
    }
    Serial.print("Counter:  ");
    Serial.println(counter);
  }
  aLastState = aState;
}
```

This should press a button (button 1) every time the pins are pushed clockwise, and press button 2 when they are moving counterclockwise. I have tried to make the counter value print out to the serial monitor to see what it was doing, but the monitor changes at random moments and doesn't recognize the rotary encoder. I can clarify any points of this, but I was wondering what I could fix.

Comment: It is strange that you can compile this code since `counter`, `aState` and `aLastState` are defined inside `setup` and should not be visible inside `loop`

Comment: I think that was an error on my part. When I was simplifying this code, I must have accidentally moved things around. I can edit it.

Comment: OK, the code seems good and coherent with what you can find on [internet](https://dronebotworkshop.com/rotary-encoders-arduino/). The random changes you describe may be caused by hardware issues.

Comment: I can try replacing my board. It's pretty old and probably not in great condition. That should help along with reinstalling the libraries.

Comment: You may also ask your question to [Arduino stackexchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/)! They can help you with both hardware and software issues

Comment: FYI you can make elementary hardware tests to verify your Arduino pins, the wires and the rotary encoder. I cannot develop too much here, since hardware stuff is out of the scope of Stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was mainly trying to verify the code as I want to narrow the issue down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this was just an interference issue. Using pullup resistors fixed the problem.